# update statement in java - pgAdmin database

Tags: java, date, jdbc

It compiles and runs ok, but when I open my table "subscription" in pgAdmin, there is no difference. Should I change something?

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE subscription SET (cancellationdate = ?)"+
                       "WHERE \"magazineID\"= ?); 


    Date cancel = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

    pst.setDate(1, cancel);
    pst.setInt(2, 4042); //this is a random id that already exist in my db

    pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Do you ever close the connection?

Comment: Why is magazineID in quotes?  Your prepareStatement does not have matched quotes and will not compile.  Look at the return value of the executeUpdate method.  It returns the number of rows updated.

Comment: magazineID is in quotes because it has capital letters, and I've found that only in this way it compiles properly.  It was the connection, I never closed it. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to:

- Commit your `Connection`
- Close your `PreparedStatement`
- Close your `Connection`

In order to see your changes in your database